# How do I fix node/npm after destroying files using npkill?

Tags: javascript, node.js, zsh, atom-editor

I tried to clear space on my hard-drive by using npkill (https://www.npmjs.com/package/npkill?fbclid=IwAR3p2n_8PWAU1RwxpX9m7_aog4zruoj_lgl7HekNSfqQkau3wqQuedUgQzQ) and accidentally deleted a lot of essential node modules, breaking a lot of files.

Today I tried re-installing a terminal into my Atom editor and got the following error:

```
> node-pty-prebuilt@0.7.6 install /private/var/folders/xy/k8mk1c6n7fd54r5374_l9zgh0000gn/T/apm-install-dir-2021412-62474-1ofwlth.z8ya/node_modules/atom-ide-terminal/node_modules/node-pty-prebuilt
> prebuild-install || node scripts/install.js


prebuild-install WARN install No prebuilt binaries found (target=9.4.4 runtime=electron arch=x64 libc= platform=darwin)
No receipt for 'com.apple.pkg.CLTools_Executables' found at '/'.

No receipt for 'com.apple.pkg.DeveloperToolsCLILeo' found at '/'.

No receipt for 'com.apple.pkg.DeveloperToolsCLI' found at '/'.

gyp: No Xcode or CLT version detected!
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/Applications/Atom.app/Contents/Resources/app/apm/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:351:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:223:5)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:272:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 20.3.0
gyp ERR! command "/Applications/Atom.app/Contents/Resources/app/apm/bin/node" "/Applications/Atom.app/Contents/Resources/app/apm/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--build_v8_with_gn=false"
gyp ERR! cwd /private/var/folders/xy/k8mk1c6n7fd54r5374_l9zgh0000gn/T/apm-install-dir-2021412-62474-1ofwlth.z8ya/node_modules/atom-ide-terminal/node_modules/node-pty-prebuilt
gyp ERR! node -v v12.14.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.1.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/private/var/folders/xy/k8mk1c6n7fd54r5374_l9zgh0000gn/T/apm-install-dir-2021412-62474-1ofwlth.z8ya/package.json'
npm WARN apm-install-dir-2021412-62474-1ofwlth.z8ya No description
npm WARN apm-install-dir-2021412-62474-1ofwlth.z8ya No repository field.
npm WARN apm-install-dir-2021412-62474-1ofwlth.z8ya No README data
npm WARN apm-install-dir-2021412-62474-1ofwlth.z8ya No license field.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! node-pty-prebuilt@0.7.6 install: `prebuild-install || node scripts/install.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the node-pty-prebuilt@0.7.6 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/generalassembly/.atom/.apm/_logs/2021-05-12T23_49_36_031Z-debug.log
```

What do I do to fix this?

*** EDIT ***

Re-installed my XCode command line tools using `xcode-select --install`, then ran the `apm install atom-ide-terminal` command again and got the following error:

````
> node-pty-prebuilt@0.7.6 install /private/var/folders/xy/k8mk1c6n7fd54r5374_l9zgh0000gn/T/apm-install-dir-2021413-64146-1l1zxmq.rf81g/node_modules/atom-ide-terminal/node_modules/node-pty-prebuilt
> prebuild-install || node scripts/install.js

  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/pty/src/unix/pty.o

prebuild-install WARN install No prebuilt binaries found (target=9.4.4 runtime=electron arch=x64 libc= platform=darwin)
In file included from ../src/unix/pty.cc:20:
In file included from ../../nan/nan.h:202:
In file included from ../../nan/nan_converters.h:67:
../../nan/nan_converters_43_inl.h:22:1: error: no viable conversion from 'Local<v8::Context>' to 'v8::Isolate *'
X(Boolean)
^~~~~~~~~~
../../nan/nan_converters_43_inl.h:18:23: note: expanded from macro 'X'
      val->To ## TYPE(isolate->GetCurrentContext())                            \
                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/generalassembly/.atom/.node-gyp/Library/Caches/node-gyp/9.4.4/include/node/v8.h:2842:37: note: passing argument to parameter 'isolate' here
  Local<Boolean> ToBoolean(Isolate* isolate) const;
                                    ^
In file included from ../src/unix/pty.cc:20:
In file included from ../../nan/nan.h:202:
In file included from ../../nan/nan_converters.h:67:
../../nan/nan_converters_43_inl.h:40:1: error: no viable conversion from 'Local<v8::Context>' to 'v8::Isolate *'
X(bool, Boolean)
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../../nan/nan_converters_43_inl.h:37:29: note: expanded from macro 'X'
  return val->NAME ## Value(isolate->GetCurrentContext());                     \
                            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/generalassembly/.atom/.node-gyp/Library/Caches/node-gyp/9.4.4/include/node/v8.h:2852:30: note: passing argument to parameter 'isolate' here
  bool BooleanValue(Isolate* isolate) const;
                             ^
In file included from ../src/unix/pty.cc:20:
In file included from ../../nan/nan.h:203:
In file included from ../../nan/nan_new.h:189:
../../nan/nan_implementation_12_inl.h:103:42: error: no viable conversion from 'v8::Isolate *' to 'Local<v8::Context>'
  return scope.Escape(v8::Function::New( isolate
                                         ^~~~~~~
/Users/generalassembly/.atom/.node-gyp/Library/Caches/node-gyp/9.4.4/include/node/v8.h:186:7: note: candidate constructor (the implicit copy constructor) not viable: no known conversion from 'v8::Isolate *' to 'const v8::Local<v8::Context> &' for 1st argument
class Local {
      ^
/Users/generalassembly/.atom/.node-gyp/Library/Caches/node-gyp/9.4.4/include/node/v8.h:186:7: note: candidate constructor (the implicit move constructor) not viable: no known conversion from 'v8::Isolate *' to 'v8::Local<v8::Context> &&' for 1st argument
/Users/generalassembly/.atom/.node-gyp/Library/Caches/node-gyp/9.4.4/include/node/v8.h:190:13: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'Local<type-parameter-0-0>' against 'v8::Isolate *'
  V8_INLINE Local(Local<S> that)
            ^
/Users/generalassembly/.atom/.node-gyp/Library/Caches/node-gyp/9.4.4/include/node/v8.h:333:22: note: explicit constructor is not a candidate
  explicit V8_INLINE Local(T* that) : val_(that) {}
                     ^
/Users/generalassembly/.atom/.node-gyp/Library/Caches/node-gyp/9.4.4/include/node/v8.h:4440:22: note: passing argument to parameter 'context' here
      Local<Context> context, FunctionCallback callback,
                     ^
In file included from ../src/unix/pty.cc:20:
In file included from ../../nan/nan.h:203:
In file included from ../../nan/nan_new.h:189:
../../nan/nan_implementation_12_inl.h:337:37: error: too few arguments to function call, expected 2, have 1
  return v8::StringObject::New(value).As<v8::StringObject>();
         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~      ^
/Users/generalassembly/.atom/.node-gyp/Library/Caches/node-gyp/9.4.4/include/node/v8.h:5841:23: note: 'New' declared here
  static Local<Value> New(Isolate* isolate, Local<String> value);
                      ^
In file included from ../src/unix/pty.cc:20:
../../nan/nan.h:1034:53: error: too few arguments to function call, single argument 'context' was not specified
      v8::Local<v8::String> string = from->ToString();
                                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^
/Users/generalassembly/.atom/.node-gyp/Library/Caches/node-gyp/9.4.4/include/node/v8.h:2804:44: note: 'ToString' declared here
  V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT MaybeLocal<String> ToString(
                                           ^
In file included from ../src/unix/pty.cc:20:
../../nan/nan.h:1044:37: error: cannot initialize a parameter of type 'v8::Isolate *' with an lvalue of type 'char *'
        length_ = string->WriteUtf8(str_, static_cast<int>(len), 0, flags);
                                    ^~~~
/Users/generalassembly/.atom/.node-gyp/Library/Caches/node-gyp/9.4.4/include/node/v8.h:3031:26: note: passing argument to parameter 'isolate' here
  int WriteUtf8(Isolate* isolate, char* buffer, int length = -1,
                         ^
In file included from ../src/unix/pty.cc:20:
../../nan/nan.h:1818:28: error: no matching member function for call to 'Set'
    New(persistentHandle)->Set(New(key).ToLocalChecked(), value);
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
/Users/generalassembly/.atom/.node-gyp/Library/Caches/node-gyp/9.4.4/include/node/v8.h:3664:37: note: candidate function not viable: requires 3 arguments, but 2 were provided
  V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT Maybe<bool> Set(Local<Context> context,
                                    ^
/Users/generalassembly/.atom/.node-gyp/Library/Caches/node-gyp/9.4.4/include/node/v8.h:3667:37: note: candidate function not viable: requires 3 arguments, but 2 were provided
  V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT Maybe<bool> Set(Local<Context> context, uint32_t index,
                                    ^
In file included from ../src/unix/pty.cc:20:
../../nan/nan.h:1824:28: error: no matching member function for call to 'Set'
    New(persistentHandle)->Set(key, value);
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
/Users/generalassembly/.atom/.node-gyp/Library/Caches/node-gyp/9.4.4/include/node/v8.h:3664:37: note: candidate function not viable: requires 3 arguments, but 2 were provided
  V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT Maybe<bool> Set(Local<Context> context,
                                    ^
/Users/generalassembly/.atom/.node-gyp/Library/Caches/node-gyp/9.4.4/include/node/v8.h:3667:37: note: candidate function not viable: requires 3 arguments, but 2 were provided
  V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT Maybe<bool> Set(Local<Context> context, uint32_t index,
                                    ^
In file included from ../src/unix/pty.cc:20:
../../nan/nan.h:1830:28: error: no matching member function for call to 'Set'
    New(persistentHandle)->Set(index, value);
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
/Users/generalassembly/.atom/.node-gyp/Library/Caches/node-gyp/9.4.4/include/node/v8.h:3664:37: note: candidate function not viable: requires 3 arguments, but 2 were provided
  V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT Maybe<bool> Set(Local<Context> context,
                                    ^
/Users/generalassembly/.atom/.node-gyp/Library/Caches/node-gyp/9.4.4/include/node/v8.h:3667:37: note: candidate function not viable: requires 3 arguments, but 2 were provided
  V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT Maybe<bool> Set(Local<Context> context, uint32_t index,
                                    ^
In file included from ../src/unix/pty.cc:20:
../../nan/nan.h:1836:32: error: no matching member function for call to 'Get'
        New(persistentHandle)->Get(New(key).ToLocalChecked()));
        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
/Users/generalassembly/.atom/.node-gyp/Library/Caches/node-gyp/9.4.4/include/node/v8.h:3711:43: note: candidate function not viable: requires 2 arguments, but 1 was provided
  V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT MaybeLocal<Value> Get(Local<Context> context,
                                          ^
/Users/generalassembly/.atom/.node-gyp/Library/Caches/node-gyp/9.4.4/include/node/v8.h:3714:43: note: candidate function not viable: requires 2 arguments, but 1 was provided
  V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT MaybeLocal<Value> Get(Local<Context> context,
                                          ^
In file included from ../src/unix/pty.cc:20:
../../nan/nan.h:1842:48: error: no matching member function for call to 'Get'
    return scope.Escape(New(persistentHandle)->Get(key));
                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
/Users/generalassembly/.atom/.node-gyp/Library/Caches/node-gyp/9.4.4/include/node/v8.h:3711:43: note: candidate function not viable: requires 2 arguments, but 1 was provided
  V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT MaybeLocal<Value> Get(Local<Context> context,
                                          ^
/Users/generalassembly/.atom/.node-gyp/Library/Caches/node-gyp/9.4.4/include/node/v8.h:3714:43: note: candidate function not viable: requires 2 arguments, but 1 was provided
  V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT MaybeLocal<Value> Get(Local<Context> context,
                                          ^
In file included from ../src/unix/pty.cc:20:
../../nan/nan.h:1847:48: error: no matching member function for call to 'Get'
    return scope.Escape(New(persistentHandle)->Get(index));
                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
/Users/generalassembly/.atom/.node-gyp/Library/Caches/node-gyp/9.4.4/include/node/v8.h:3711:43: note: candidate function not viable: requires 2 arguments, but 1 was provided
  V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT MaybeLocal<Value> Get(Local<Context> context,
                                          ^
/Users/generalassembly/.atom/.node-gyp/Library/Caches/node-gyp/9.4.4/include/node/v8.h:3714:43: note: candidate function not viable: requires 2 arguments, but 1 was provided
  V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT MaybeLocal<Value> Get(Local<Context> context,
                                          ^
In file included from ../src/unix/pty.cc:20:
In file included from ../../nan/nan.h:2657:
../../nan/nan_object_wrap.h:24:25: error: no member named 'IsNearDeath' in 'Nan::Persistent<v8::Object>'
    assert(persistent().IsNearDeath());
           ~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/assert.h:93:25: note: expanded from macro 'assert'
    (__builtin_expect(!(e), 0) ? __assert_rtn(__func__, __FILE__, __LINE__, #e) : (void)0)
                        ^
In file included from ../src/unix/pty.cc:20:
In file included from ../../nan/nan.h:2657:
../../nan/nan_object_wrap.h:67:18: error: no member named 'MarkIndependent' in 'Nan::Persistent<v8::Object>'
    persistent().MarkIndependent();
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^
../../nan/nan_object_wrap.h:124:26: error: no member named 'IsNearDeath' in 'Nan::Persistent<v8::Object>'
    assert(wrap->handle_.IsNearDeath());
           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/assert.h:93:25: note: expanded from macro 'assert'
    (__builtin_expect(!(e), 0) ? __assert_rtn(__func__, __FILE__, __LINE__, #e) : (void)0)
                        ^
In file included from ../src/unix/pty.cc:20:
In file included from ../../nan/nan.h:2753:
../../nan/nan_typedarray_contents.h:34:43: warning: 'GetContents' is deprecated: Use GetBackingStore. See http://crbug.com/v8/9908. [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
      data   = static_cast<char*>(buffer->GetContents().Data()) + byte_offset;
                                          ^
/Users/generalassembly/.atom/.node-gyp/Library/Caches/node-gyp/9.4.4/include/node/v8.h:5259:3: note: 'GetContents' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
  V8_DEPRECATE_SOON("Use GetBackingStore. See http://crbug.com/v8/9908.")
  ^
/Users/generalassembly/.atom/.node-gyp/Library/Caches/node-gyp/9.4.4/include/node/v8config.h:408:41: note: expanded from macro 'V8_DEPRECATE_SOON'
#   define V8_DEPRECATE_SOON(message) [[deprecated(message)]]
                                        ^
../src/unix/pty.cc:161:48: error: too few arguments to function call, single argument 'context' was not specified
  v8::String::Utf8Value file(info[0]->ToString());
                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^
/Users/generalassembly/.atom/.node-gyp/Library/Caches/node-gyp/9.4.4/include/node/v8.h:2804:44: note: 'ToString' declared here
  V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT MaybeLocal<String> ToString(
                                           ^
../src/unix/pty.cc:172:38: error: no matching member function for call to 'Get'
    v8::String::Utf8Value arg(argv_->Get(Nan::New<v8::Integer>(i))->ToString());
                              ~~~~~~~^~~
/Users/generalassembly/.atom/.node-gyp/Library/Caches/node-gyp/9.4.4/include/node/v8.h:3711:43: note: candidate function not viable: requires 2 arguments, but 1 was provided
  V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT MaybeLocal<Value> Get(Local<Context> context,
                                          ^
/Users/generalassembly/.atom/.node-gyp/Library/Caches/node-gyp/9.4.4/include/node/v8.h:3714:43: note: candidate function not viable: requires 2 arguments, but 1 was provided
  V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT MaybeLocal<Value> Get(Local<Context> context,
                                          ^
../src/unix/pty.cc:183:38: error: no matching member function for call to 'Get'
    v8::String::Utf8Value pair(env_->Get(Nan::New<v8::Integer>(i))->ToString());
                               ~~~~~~^~~
/Users/generalassembly/.atom/.node-gyp/Library/Caches/node-gyp/9.4.4/include/node/v8.h:3711:43: note: candidate function not viable: requires 2 arguments, but 1 was provided
  V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT MaybeLocal<Value> Get(Local<Context> context,
                                          ^
/Users/generalassembly/.atom/.node-gyp/Library/Caches/node-gyp/9.4.4/include/node/v8.h:3714:43: note: candidate function not viable: requires 2 arguments, but 1 was provided
  V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT MaybeLocal<Value> Get(Local<Context> context,
                                          ^
../src/unix/pty.cc:188:48: error: too few arguments to function call, single argument 'context' was not specified
  v8::String::Utf8Value cwd_(info[3]->ToString());
                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^
/Users/generalassembly/.atom/.node-gyp/Library/Caches/node-gyp/9.4.4/include/node/v8.h:2804:44: note: 'ToString' declared here
  V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT MaybeLocal<String> ToString(
                                           ^
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
1 warning and 20 errors generated.
make: *** [Release/obj.target/pty/src/unix/pty.o] Error 1
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/Applications/Atom.app/Contents/Resources/app/apm/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:194:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:223:5)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:272:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 20.3.0
gyp ERR! command "/Applications/Atom.app/Contents/Resources/app/apm/bin/node" "/Applications/Atom.app/Contents/Resources/app/apm/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--build_v8_with_gn=false"
gyp ERR! cwd /private/var/folders/xy/k8mk1c6n7fd54r5374_l9zgh0000gn/T/apm-install-dir-2021413-64146-1l1zxmq.rf81g/node_modules/atom-ide-terminal/node_modules/node-pty-prebuilt
gyp ERR! node -v v12.14.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.1.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/private/var/folders/xy/k8mk1c6n7fd54r5374_l9zgh0000gn/T/apm-install-dir-2021413-64146-1l1zxmq.rf81g/package.json'
npm WARN apm-install-dir-2021413-64146-1l1zxmq.rf81g No description
npm WARN apm-install-dir-2021413-64146-1l1zxmq.rf81g No repository field.
npm WARN apm-install-dir-2021413-64146-1l1zxmq.rf81g No README data
npm WARN apm-install-dir-2021413-64146-1l1zxmq.rf81g No license field.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! node-pty-prebuilt@0.7.6 install: `prebuild-install || node scripts/install.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the node-pty-prebuilt@0.7.6 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/generalassembly/.atom/.apm/_logs/2021-05-13T07_51_52_192Z-debug.log ```
````

Comment: Does your project have a Package.json if yes then just run ```npm install``` and all should be okay

Comment: Looks like you might've uninstalled developer tools. Try running `xcode-select --install`

Comment: @Nisala Thank you for replying - I ran the `xcode-select --install` command, and afterwards tried running the `apm install` command and got a different, much longer error message.